# How to declare/provide file path in JQuery which is emeeded in the Wordpress theme

Tags: jquery, paths

How to give the source location path in the jquery code, where my file is in 
**cah-new/wp-content/themes/theme_name/includes/func.php** and i have to give that path in the jquery code

```
$.get(\"func.php\", {
```

kindly help me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.get('<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url')?>/includes/func.php', {
```